# How can I use the verb "sad" in the past continuous?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

How can I use the verb "sad" in the past continuous? E.g.:

> I was crying.
>   I was missing.

What should be the sentences for *sad* or *upset* in past continuous? Why do some words like the two above not follow standards? Are these exceptions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Sad* is an adjective, so it doesn't have a past form. You'd just say:

> I was sad.

There is the verb [*sadden*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sadden), however.

> I was saddened.

*Upset* can be a verb, but it's an irregular one. Its simple past (and past participle) form is *upset*.

> I was upset.
>   I was upset by the news.
>   The bad news upset me.

Note that both *sadden* and *upset* are transitive verbs. (The intransitive usage of *sadden* is archaic.) So if you are going for past continuous, simply saying

> I was upsetting.
>   I was saddening.

wouldn't really work — it would raise the question, *whom* were you upsetting/saddening? So instead, you would have to say

> I was being upset (by something).
>   I was being saddened (by something).

Comment: Upsetting/Saddening can be used as a present participle with subject and object flipped around; e.g., "[Something] was upsetting" with an implied object.

Comment: I think native speakers would be much more likely to say "I was feeling upset" than "I was being upset" (unless they were being knocked over, or being defeated in a game).

Answer (score 6):

There is no verb "sad" in English. It's an adjective. The closest you can get is "feel sad", which you *can* put in the past continuous:

> I was feeling sad.

Similarly, you can write

> I was feeling upset.

Answer (score 3):

*Cry* and *miss* are two verbs; that is the reason you can say "I was crying" or "I was missing."
*Upset* is also verb, but it means "to make others unhappy;" if that is what you mean, then you can use the past progressive of *upset* like you do with other verbs.
*Upset* and *sad* are two adjectives, in sentences like "I am upset" or "I am sad." If you want to use the past progressive, the verb in those phrases is *to be*, whose present participle is *being*. I have never seen somebody using the past progressive in that way, though, when you can simply write those phrases with the simple past.